# Python Ruamel YAML loading comments with aliases and merge keys

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

Ruamel doesn't seem to copy comments over during alias expansion with merge keys (it does with a regular anchors), at least by default.  Is there a way to do this?

Example: If I load this sample YAML file:

```
aliases:
  - &a1
    b1: 5         # Comment for b1=5
    c1: 3         # Comment for c1=3

model:
  obj1:
    <<: *a1
    d1: 7         # Comment for d1=7
  obj2:
    *a1
  obj3:
    *a1
```

With this code:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

with open("test.yaml") as fp:
    d = yaml.load(fp, yaml.RoundTripLoader)

def showcmts(d):
    for k,v in d.items():
        print("Key {} has {}".format(k, (d.ca.items[k][2] if k in d.ca.items and d.ca.items[k][2] is not None else "no comment")))

print("Model obj1 contents and comments are:")
showcmts(d["model"]["obj1"])
print("Model obj2 contents and comments are:")
showcmts(d["model"]["obj2"])
print("Model obj3 contents and comments are:")
showcmts(d["model"]["obj3"])
```

I get this output:

```
Model obj1 contents and comments are:
Key d1 has CommentToken('# Comment for d1=7\n', line: 8, col: 18)
Key b1 has no comment
Key c1 has no comment
Model obj2 contents and comments are:
Key b1 has CommentToken('# Comment for b1=5\n', line: 2, col: 18)
Key c1 has CommentToken('# Comment for c1=3\n\n', line: 3, col: 18)
Model obj3 contents and comments are:
Key b1 has CommentToken('# Comment for b1=5\n', line: 2, col: 18)
Key c1 has CommentToken('# Comment for c1=3\n\n', line: 3, col: 18)
```

The comments have loaded for the anchor, and does indeed copy if there are multiples (the test I did with obj3), but not the merge (which I need it to do for a project I'm working on).

Thoughts? Bug?

Thanks

Comment: This is as designed. On a mapping with a merge you can walk over all the keys, but that is just because the `.items()` method recurses in the merged mappings (for keys not yet seen). There is (of course) no such recursion done if you access `.ca.items()`.`

Comment: So how can I get the comments on the merged items?

Comment: And I guess why the "of course" for the no such recursion on .ca.items()?

Comment: Because it is not necessary to have recursion there, to dump the data structure properly, the merge is not executed. `.items()`, for convenience sake of extracting the data, acts as if you had done a more traditional `.load()`. It looks to me like you should ask a different question, in which you clearly state what you want to achieve, and how you can achieve that, instead of what you get doing what you do. My thoughts on that are exactly "of course it works like that, that was how I designed it". Sorry if that fulfill whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: I thought I did at the end - "The comments have loaded for the anchor, and does indeed copy if there are multiples (the test I did with obj3), but not the merge (which I need it to do for a project I'm working on)."  

Basically, I need to inspect and have my code parse the comments for all the data fields that come in via the YAML file (which is generated elsewhere), including values merged in.

Comment: The code is successful on everything else with code similar to the above (for basic key: value # comments, and for anchors brought in entirely via the "*a1" type syntax), but the merge's comments being missing is causing problems.